# Workstation for Software Developer with Visual Studio, SQL-Server

Tags: cpu, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, workstation

I must do a decision between the following two systems with different CPU's. I asking me, is there a difference/advantage when I use the dual cpu machine for working Visual Studio 2013 (or higher) and SQL-Server 2014?

```
First:
- 1x Processor Intel Xeon E5-1680v2
- Memory 32GB DDR3-1866
- Harddisk SSD 512 GB Samsung

Second:
- 2x Processor Intel Xeon E5-2650v2
- Memory 32GB DDR3-1866
- Harddisk SSD 512 GB Samsung
```

the second machine is a more expensive then the first one. The question is: is there an advantage in working speed with the second machine?

Comment: Yes. Deding on how you use it it can be both SLOWER or much faster. 

Dual socket setups are quite different. Dual path to the memory (Up to twice the speed), but also localised memory (If CPU2 needs to get to the data connected to the lines on CPU1 it will be slower).

So there is no answer except: "I varies. Dual core setups are often faster".

Comment: Thanks Hennes. Perhaps you can do a statement on this information: The PC with one CPU its a HP Workstation Z420 and the one with 2 CPU's is a HP Workstation Z620

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am reminded of a car analogy: *What is better? A truck of a formula-1 race car?*
The answer is ofcource *It depends on what you want to do with the car.*

The same is true in your case, though you gave a reasonable good description of your goals. I am keeping the answer rather generic though because answers are supposed to help future readers. Not just the original poster of the question.

You stated:

- Visual Studio 2013
- SQL-Server 2014

Visual studio is an IDE for developement and compiling. It benefits from a fast CPU. When compiling a large project with thousands of small source files it also benefits from fast IO.

- SQL server (and databases in general) may depend a lot on the CPU speed. Or not. If they just have to read from a table and return that value then they do not need much speed. If your SQL quaries are complex inner and outer joins, then it may use a lot more CPU.  (Recap: It depends on what you do in the database).
- SQL also likes fast IO. Either via the IO subsystem or with the help of a lot of memory.

The [E5-1680](http://ark.intel.com/products/77912/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-1680-v2-25M-Cache-3_00-GHz?q=E5-1680v2) will win it from the [E5-2650](http://ark.intel.com/products/75269/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2650-v2-20M-Cache-2_60-GHz?q=%20E5-2650v2) when you do relative simple tasks. It has a higher clock speed (both base and turbo'd). It has a bigger cache. It seems superior. If you have to choose between a single E5-1680v2 and a single E5-2650v2 then the choice is clear.

The dual 2650 setup however has some differences which can turn into big advantages. Lets iterate over these differences:

- The setup can use two CPU's. That is twice 8 cores. It has the potential to be a lot faster.
- The dual setup has a total of 40MB cache. The single setup has 25MB. If your working set is larger than 25MB and the dual setup will be a lot faster.
- The dual setup has two memory controllers. It can archive up to twice the bandwidth. (Very relevant when the data does not fit into the caches. Mostly useless if it does).
- It can address much more memory (768GB vs 256GB).  (Moot point in your case since you will fill it with 32GB)
- The E2650 has on-die PCI-e channels. This likely results in better expandability and becomes relevant in situations where you want four+ CUDA cards.

Downsides:

- Two CPU's -> Twice the costprice of a CPU
- Two CPU's -> Up to twice the power usage (2x95=190Watt Watt TPD, though the 1680v2 has a 130W TPD)
- If you only populate one CPU then some of the PCI-e slots might not work. (Specifically, those who connect to the PCI-e lanes of the missing CPU).
- Same thing for the RAM slots.
- Finally, you have two chips with separate caches and memory. If applications are localised this will work out great. If an application needs data which is connected via another CPU (or in the cache or via  the others CPU's memory controller) then it will be slower.

Comment: +1 just for the effort, although I do think you should possibly create a new self answered question with this as the answer - many Q's on SU could benefit from this answer!